# Home network goes down when Access Point (AP) loses power/reboots

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point, reboot

I have 200/200 fiber from my local co-op.  I use their Zyxel EMG3425 as the main router (gateway, since they had to do a custom setup with IPs and whatnot, but it's wifi is disabled).  I use 2 old Netgear routers as AP's at different ends of the house- an R6400 and R8000 with different SSIDs.  The Zyxel and R8000 are on a UPS.  If power flickers (or the R6400 loses power/reboots) the entire network goes down.  Computers connected via ethernet to the R8000 lose internet.  Wifi for my network shows but no connection is possible to the internet.  I have to go through and reboot the main Zyxel router and both AP's to get things back up.  I have reserved the IP addresses to the two AP's in the Zyxel but that didn't help.  I can test by just turning the R6400 off and on and it will take the network down.
Each AP is connected to a different LAN port on the Zyxel.
This didn't happen when I had a wireless extender (TP link that just plugs into an outlet and uses wireless backhaul) set as a different SSID.  If it lost power/rebooted then it would just reconnect and broadcast it's SSID.  That wireless repeater wasn't optimal for my kids so I went with the wired AP (R6400) at their end.  That's when the issues started.  I thought that when the R6400 rebooted it would just get it's IP and reconnect devices but it doesn't and the network goes down.

Comment: Try updating firmware or newer equipment. No such issue here (routers plus AP)

Comment: Make sure you've disabled the NAT and DHCP Server features of your R6400. You don't want any devices accidentally getting a DHCP lease from it and then using it as a NAT gateway. It should just be a dumb bridge between Ethernet and Wi-Fi.

Comment: It says the firmware is up to date (it's an old model, so I doubt they will be providing updates).  I went through the setup wizard and set it up as a Wireless AP when I first installed it.  There are plenty of settings that are now disabled- WAN/LAN setup being two of them.  There is no access to settings for DHCP or NAT in this mode.

Comment: It’s possible you have a power surge issue. Ethernet surge protectors exist, but I don’t know whether they’re effective. // Also, even on switched networks, bad/broken actors can saturate the network with invalid packets. Do the port LEDs show activity?

Comment: Port LEDs seem to show they are trying to communicate, but the Internet LED is amber instead of the normal white.  The same happened on the other R8000 and the main Router (well, the Internet icon stopped blinking since it doesn't change color).  I noticed those after my desktop, wired to the R8000 indicated a loss of internet.  The LAN lights continue to blink some.

Comment: Update:  I unplugged the ethernet cable from the Zyxel gateway (at the R6400) and rebooted the router, then plugged the ethernet back in and no issue.  I have changed the R8000 router with an Asus unit (converting to the mesh system) and power cycling the R6400 with the network cable attached still shuts everything down and requires a complete reboot all the way back to the Zyxel gateway.  Hopefully it wont be an issue much longer as I have another Asus mesh wifi 6 router on the way to swap with the R6400.

Comment: Replaced both Netgear routers (setup as AP's) with Asus RT-AX82U units (as AP's).  Still using the Zyxel gateway/router (wifi off).  Set up AiMesh.  Have not had the same issue with these units.  Unplugged the Asus unit that is in the same place as the Netgear R6400 and no issue when booting back up.  Must have been an issue with that Netgear unit.  Still unable to pinpoint the cause, but I'll consider this closed since the units were replaced and the new setup is working as expected.